# Including nonfree module in eclipse openCV 3.0 project

Tags: eclipse, javacv, opencv3.0, surf

I want to use some functionality from nonfree library so I added javacv to my maven project and I have installed opencv_contrib package.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

As a result I have opencv_xfeatures2d.class as a part of opencv-3.0.0-1.1.jar library.

I have following import:

```
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_xfeatures2d.*;
```

in my project. The library is added properly because following

```
SURF surf = new SURF();
```

line (ctrl + left mouse button) it redirects me to proper function inside opencv_xfeatures2d file. But when I try to compile project I get following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   jniopencv_xfeatures2d in java.library.path    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)  at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)    at
>   org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:597)  at
>   org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:438)     at
>   org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:381)     at
>   org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_xfeatures2d.(opencv_xfeatures2d.java:19)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)   at
>   org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:413)     at
>   org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:381)     at
>   org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_xfeatures2d$SURF.(opencv_xfeatures2d.java:489)
>     at mypr.rec.Clsm.Cmpr(Clsm.java:18)     at
>   mypr.mn.Main.main(Main.java:21) Caused by:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   /tmp/javacpp8449996504597/libjniopencv_xfeatures2d.so:
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.0: undefined symbol:
>   ippicvJumpIndexForMergedLibs  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)     at
>   java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)   at
>   org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:580)  ... 10 more

The strange thing is that it says about **jniopencv**_xfeatures2d instead of **opencv**_xfeatures2d. What am I doing wrong?